# Is www required in front of a domain name, in Google Analytics?

Tags: google, google-analytics, google-search-console, google-search, analytics

I have a website (let's call it `example.com`). It can be accessed as example.com and also as `www.example.com`. I just added `example.com` in Google Search Console as property (it appears as `example.com`, without `www`).

Question: Should I include also the `www.example.com` as property?

Comment: "Adding a property" is typically done in Google Search Console, not in Google Analytics.  You also tagged this [tag:google-search-console].   Is Google Analytics actually involved here at all?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - sorry, I fixed that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Google Search Console you want to either verify a property at the domain level, which means all url prefix variants like www and http/https are included, or verify all url prefix variants separately.

Serving content on different url prefixes is not advised, pick one and have all the others redirect to it.

With Google Analytics url prefix does not matter. It tracks based on where the tracking code is placed. If it's on all url prefix variants, it tracks all.

However, if you want to link your Google Analytics to the Google Search Console, you can't do it via the domain level (Last I checked). You have to pick one url prefix variant and link to that.

Comment: Thanks for this very nice and useful answer.  What are the implications (if any) of your very last phrase? "You have to pick one url prefix variant and link to that"

Comment: Nothing major. If you want to see GSC data in GA, you can only select one property and it has to be a url prefix one. I personally don't connect them. I go direct to GSC for data.